# How to replace two or more strings in a file in tcl

Tags: replace, tcl

I am reading a file and trying to replace 3 strings in different lines using `regsub`.

**Input file :**

```
This is a bus
This is a car 
This is a bike
```

**Output Expected:**

```
This is a Plane
This is a Scooter
This is a Bicycle
```

if i use

```
puts $out [regsub -all "( bus)" $line "\ $x" ]
puts $out [regsub -all "( car)" $line "\ $y" ]
puts $out [regsub -all "( bike)" $line "\ $z" ]
```

As i am calling as a proc with arguments x,y,z as plane,scooter,bicycle.
But This is printing all lines 3 times. How to replace all three strings ??

Comment: Are you reading the file line by line ?

Comment: Yes reading a file line by line..

Comment: No need to escape the space in the quoted replacement string.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `string map` to replace strings:

```
string map {{ bus} { Plane} { car} { Scooter} { bike} { Bicycle}} $input_string
```

The arguments are a list of pairs of "find" "replace" strings and then your input string...

BTW. With the `regsub` method, you can nest the regsubs, so that the result of one becomes the input of the other e.g. with two: `regsub -all { bus} [regsub -all { car} $input_string { Scooter}] { Plane}` it isn't very readable though!

Also note that you don't need to capture the group with parentheses in your expression: `"( car)"` would do an extra sub-group capture that you don't actually use... `{ car}` is better...

Comment: Hi Captain,Thanx for your reply, but how to get a value of a variable with String map, coz if when i tried to get value of x while replacing its still printing as $x, Here is what i tried, set x Scooter
puts  [string map {{bus} {Plane} {car } { "$x"} {bike} { bicycle}} $line]
Output: This is a Plane
This is a  "$x"
This is a  bicycle

Comment: If you want to do the variables, you build up the list using those... e.g. `string map [list { bus} " $x" { car} " $y" { bike} " $z"] $input_string`

Answer (score 1):

The clearest way is to write the line to a variable in-between each substitution. Writing back to the variable it came from is quite often the easiest approach. You can then print the result out once at the end.

```
set line [regsub -all "( bus)" $line "\ $x"]
set line [regsub -all "( car)" $line "\ $y"]
set line [regsub -all "( bike)" $line "\ $z"]
puts $out $line
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you read file line by line you can use **if** operator.

```
while { [ gets $fh line ] >= 0} {
    if {[regexp -all -- { bus} $line]} {
        puts $out [regsub -all "( bus)" $line "\ $x" ]
    } elseif {[regexp -all -- { car} $line]} {
        puts $out [regsub -all "( car)" $line "\ $y" ]
    } else {
        puts $out [regsub -all "( bike)" $line "\ $z" ]
    }
}
```